# Configurar url dinamicas centos

Tags: host

Saludos estoy intentado crear reglas para que al momento que acceda a una url identifique mi Base de Datos y la Aplicacion a la que se desea acceder ejemplo:

```
http://3.911.911.1/miempresa/miaplicacion
```

en esta caso mi direccion web es una IP de Amazon Services la idea es identificar el primer parametro "miempresa" el cual me sirve para seleccionar mi base de datos con Django y el segundo parametro es "miaplicacion" que es la aplicacion que se desea acceder.

he configurado mi host de la siguiente manera:

```
127.0.0.1   3.911.911.1
```

al acceder a dicha IP redirecciona a localhost., puedo hacer que reconosca mi direccion url estoy usando **django-db-multitenant**.

agradezco cualquier sugerencia.

Comment: no te serviría utilizar NGINX como reverse proxy? https://linode.com/docs/web-servers/nginx/use-nginx-reverse-proxy/ Tal vez la parte de **reverse proxy** te sirva